# Trying to proxy Jira through 2 nginx reverse proxies images and css do not load

Tags: nginx, proxy, jira, reverse-proxy

I am trying to use nginx to reverse proxy through two proxies I have a server that handles all https traffic and a separate server runs Confluence and Jira. I have the first nginx proxy configured like

```
ssl on;
ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/cert.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem;

access_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.mydomain.com.access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.mydomain.com.error.log;

server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;

root /var/www/mydomain.com/html;
index index.html;

location / {
     try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
location /jira {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass              http://jira.home.mydomain.com;
}
```

The second nginx proxy is configured as

```
listen jira.home.mydomain.com:80;
server_name jira.home.mydomain.com;
location / {
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
}
```

If I go to the second proxy directly JIRA works fine. But trying to go from external to Jira(through the first and second proxy) it doesn't load the css or images.
I am trying to use mydomain.com/JIRA to access JIRA at jira.home.mydomain.com
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As per the [official troubleshooting guide](https://confluence.atlassian.com/kb/reverse-proxy-and-application-link-troubleshooting-guide-719095279.html), try disabling gzip on nginx since the traffic is already encoded.

Worked for me on jira + ssl + nginx reverse proxy

Answer (score -1):

Seeing other posts the following line may cause the issue:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
```